# The distribution of K until the n-th occurance of a poisson process takes place

Tags: poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

Let's take the following scenario:

Customers arrive at a shopping mall according to a Poisson process with a rate of `λ` per minute. The mall has a door that closes if nobody passes for two minutes, and it will reopen when someone arrives.

The variable `K_n` represents the number of times the door closes before the `nth` person arrives.

- What's the distribution of `K_n`?
- Find the limit of `K_n/n` as n tends to infinity.

I started by calculating the probability that no one would arrive within 2-minute intervals and I got the following:

```
X: number of arrivals in 2 minutes
probability that 0 person arrives in 2 minutes p(0,2) = (2.λ^0.e^-2λ)/(0!) = e^-2λ
```

which is the same as `P(T > t)` where `T` is the time until the first arrival ==> `T` is exponentially distributed.

However, I am not sure how this can be linked to `n` and the arrival of the `K_n` person.

I tried to reason as follows:

if we record each arrival and count `K_n`, then this counter will remain the same if the interval `t` between the current arrival and the next one is less than 2, and will increase by one if the interval `t` is 2 or more, and the probability that `t` is less or more than 2 follows an exponential distribution.

But how to model the distribution of `K_n` gathering all of this? or am I missing something?

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Hint:  Each interarrival time is either less than or greater than two minutes, with the probabilities as you have derived them.   There are $n$ of these interarrival times.   Are you actually interested in the interarrival times themselves, or in the binary events "interarrival time > 2 minutes?"

Comment: @jbowman I want to get the distribution of `K_n` which is the number of door closes.
For one interval, I have a `e^-2λ` chance that it has a length of 2 or more (`K` for this interval is 1) and  `1 - e^-2λ` that it's shorter than 2 minutes  (`K` for this interval is 0) and this is repeated  `n` times until the nth person arrives. What I explained is the expected value of `K_n` right? so what's its probability distribution?

Comment: Can you name the distribution of $K_1$, i.e., whether or not the door is closed when the first person arrives?  If you can do that, the distribution of $K_n$ will follow.

Comment: @jbowman Well working with your hints, `K_1` which is the count of door closes in one interval would be a Bernoulli that has values 1 or 0 with probabilities `e^-2λ` and `1 - e^-2λ` respectively ==> the overall `K_n` is Binomial. Hope this is correct.

Comment: Very good, you've got it!

Comment: @jbowman thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @jbowman, Here is the final answer:

For one interval (time between 2 people's arrivals), either the interval is less than 2 minutes ==> the door doesn't close, or it is 2 minutes or more ==> the door closes.

Since people are arriving based on a Poisson process, we can use that to calculate the probability that an interval is longer than 2 minutes.

As mentioned in the question, the probability that an interval is longer than 2 minutes is the same as the probability that no person arrived until time = 2 So if $X$ is a random variable for the number of people arriving in 2 minutes $p(0,2) = \frac{(2λ)^0e^{-2λ}}{0!} = e^{-2λ} = P(T >= 2)$

So if we take one interval and define $K_i$ as the number of door closes, then $K_i = 1$ with probability $e^{-2λ}$ and $K_i = 0$ with probability $1 - e^{-2λ}$.

From that we notice that the distribution of $K_i$ is Bernoulli and this means that the overall distribution of $K_n$ is a Binomial (a repetition of a Bernoulli trial $n$ times).